# cython: Cythonizing a large dict lookup

Tags: python, dictionary, gcc, cython, cythonize

Given a script with only a hardcoded lookup dictionary, I was wondering if compiling it using Cython gave any performance gain.

The dictionary file looks like described below and is around 5Mb. The generated c-file is around 65Mb. Compilation takes ages. Is there a way to reduce the size of the generated c-file and/or speed up the compilation? Alternatively, is there a fundamental reason why this approach would not work?

filename.py:

```py
lookup_dict = {
     0: {"Value 1"},
     2: {"Value 2", "Something else"},
     3: {"Some other value"},
     # (...)
     99996: {"one", "two", "three value"},
     100000: {"Another value"},
}

def lookup(idx: int) -> set:
    try:
        return lookup_dict[idx]
    except KeyError:
        return set()
```

The Python setup.py script:

```py
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension

from Cython.Build import cythonize
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext

ext_modules = cythonize(
    [Extension("lookup_module", [r"filename.py"])], language_level="3"
)

setup(
    name="Lookup Module",
    cmdclass={"build_ext": build_ext},
    ext_modules=ext_modules,
)
```

Which is then called using:

```sh
python setup.py build_ext --inplace
```

(gcc version 7.4.0, Ubuntu 18.04)

Comment: Do you have an entry for every value between 0 and 10000? Because if so why not use a tuple instead?

Comment: @DavidW: There are entries missing (such as 1 in the example). I've updated the example to make it clearer

Comment: I should have spotted that. It might still be worth creating a tuple with `None` for the missing values (or similar). To be honest this isn't the sort of thing Cython really helps with though.